# How do I map an OData query against a DTO to another entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

My question is very similar to this one: [How do I map an OData query against a DTO to an EF entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969225/how-do-i-map-an-odata-query-against-a-dto-to-an-ef-entity)
I have a simple setup to test the ASP.NET Web API OData V4 $filter functionality. What I would like to do is to “alias” some properties of the ProductDTO to match the properties of Product entity. The user will call the ProductsController for example with the following request:

> GET products?$filter=DisplayName eq ‘test’

The Product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public Product()
    { }
}
```

The ProductDTO class:

```
public class ProductDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int DisplayLevel { get; set; }
    public ProductDTO(Product product)
    {
        this.DisplayName = product.Name;
        this.DisplayLevel = product.Level;
    }
}
```

The ProductsController:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Product> q)
    {
        IQueryable<Product> products = this._products.AsQueryable();
        if (q.Filter != null) products = q.Filter.ApplyTo(this._products.AsQueryable(), new ODataQuerySettings()) as IQueryable<Product>;
        return products.Select(p => new ProductDTO(p));
    }
}
```

Of course I’m getting the following exception:

> Could not find a property named 'DisplayName' on type 'TestAPI.Models.Product'

I tried to use the newly introduced aliasing feature by adding the following lines to the WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        …
        IEdmModel model = GetModel();
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("*", "*", model);
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        EntitySetConfiguration<Product> products = builder.EntitySet<Product>("Product");
        products.EntityType.Property(p => p.Name).Name = "DisplayName";
        products.EntityType.Property(p => p.Level).Name = "DisplayLevel";
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

I suppose that I'm using the aliasing feature incorrectly, because the same exception as described above is thrown. If I invoke the following request it works, but this is not what I'm trying to achieve:

> GET products?$filter=Name eq ‘test’

Update:

I agree with gdoron, the `Get` endpoint should look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ProductDTO> q)
```

But this should be solvable without AutoMapper?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a solution without using AutoMapper.

The ProductsController now looks like this:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ProductDTO> q)
    {
        IQueryable<Product> products = this._products.AsQueryable();

        IEdmModel model = GetModel();
        IEdmType type = model.FindDeclaredType("TestAPI.Models.Product");
        IEdmNavigationSource source = model.FindDeclaredEntitySet("Products");
        ODataQueryOptionParser parser = new ODataQueryOptionParser(model, type, source, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "$filter", q.Filter.RawValue } });
        ODataQueryContext context = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(Product), q.Context.Path);
        FilterQueryOption filter = new FilterQueryOption(q.Filter.RawValue, context, parser);

        if (filter != null) products = filter.ApplyTo(products, new ODataQuerySettings()) as IQueryable<Product>;
        return products.Select(p => new ProductDTO(p));
    }
}
```

The WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        …
        IEdmModel model = GetModel();
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("*", "*", model);
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetModel()
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        EntitySetConfiguration<Product> product = builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        product.EntityType.Name = "Product";
        product.EntityType.Namespace = "TestAPI.Models";
        product.EntityType.Property(p => p.Name).Name = "DisplayName";
        product.EntityType.Property(p => p.Level).Name = "DisplayLevel";
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: smart! why use automapper while you can do it completely with C#. It can also be done with queryable and Expression Tree.

Comment: ODataQueryOptions only supports $filter, $orderby, $top, $skip .

Comment: If someone needs  `new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(TypeName), q.Context.Path)` can also be `new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(TypeName), null)`

Comment: hi @niklr, can you answer this question? thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650392/net-core-using-odata-in-onion-architecture-mapping-query-parameters-from-dto-t

Answer (score 10):

If you decided you want to use DTOs (which is definitely a good idea in my opinion), then use it...
The `$metadata` should reflect the DTO's properties names and not of the EF entity, since this is what clients get and this is what the clients should send.
It means you should change the `Get` endpoint to something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ProductDTO> q)
```

To avoid the coupling between `ProductDTO` and `Product` you can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map between the classes for you. Also, if you use AutoMapper's `Project` method, you can cleanup you methods to somthing like:

```
public IQueryable<ProductDTO> Get(ProductDTO dto)
```

You can check [Asp.net official demo for versioning](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataVersioningSample/), it heavily uses DTOs and AutoMapper, it will give you a good direction, just ignore the versioning if it doesn't interest you now.

Comment: These sample are nice but sadly I do not see away around transforming calculated fields (ones that are not stored in the database but calculated in memory when called). I would rather not duplicate my code in the view-models for handling business state logic. I would like to expose some of those calculated fields to the user though. Any tips that would allow me to use AutoMapper?

Answer (score 6):

For those using .NET 6 with [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.8`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/8.0.8) you can do it like so:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _context;

    public ProductsController(MyDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context; 
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ProductDto> Get()
    {
        return _context.Products
            .Select(p => new ProductDTO()
            {
                DisplayName = p.Name,
                DisplayLevel = p.Level
            });
    }
}
```

And in your startup:

```
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddOData(opt => opt.Filter().Select())
```

Note that the key is in the projection. Changing it to `.Select(p => new ProductDto(p)` will not work since it cannot be translated into SQL. There is no longer any need for an EDM-model.

Given there's a table named `Products` that look something like this:

[image]

A `GET` for this url:

`http://localhost:XXXX/products?$filter=DisplayName eq 'Emma'&select=DisplayLevel`

The result will be:

```
[{"DisplayLevel":3}]
```

Will generate a SQL looking something like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [p].[Level], [p].[Name]
FROM [Products] AS [p]
WHERE [p].[Name] = @__TypedProperty_0',N'@__TypedProperty_0 nvarchar(4000)',@__TypedProperty_0=N'Emma'
```

As can be seen in the SQL there is a downside with this approach and that is that the entire model `Name` and `Level` is fetched from the database despite the select in the url only requests `DisplayLevel`. This is probably a limitation due to the projection.

A complete example can be found here:
https://github.com/smoksnes/ODataExample

Comment: But there is no Product.DisplayName, so $select will not work. You need to have mapping between entity and DTO.

Comment: @TomasVoracek - That was an unfortunate mistake. I've updated the code and also added some more details.

Answer (score 3):

Try using AutoMapper, you will need to add these references to your controller

```
using AutoMapper;
using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
```

Your method

```
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
public IQueryable<ObjectDTO> Get()
{
    return dbContext.Entities.ProjectTo<ObjectDTO>();
}
```

In your global

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        //Usually in a diff class Mapping.ConfigureDataTransferObjects();
        Mapper.CreateMap<MyEntity, ObjectDTO>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectDTO, MyEntity>();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To me the solution was just adding the DTO to the EDM config (v4):

```
edmBuilder.EntitySet<Contact>("Contacts");
edmBuilder.EntityType<ContactDto>();
```

Comment: I was looking to expose just the DTO in the $metadata endpoint. Using EntityType<MyDto> instead of EntitySet worked for me. Thanks Shimmy.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick, you can fill a destinationvalue from a calculated sourceValue, like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDTO>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.InvoiceCount, opt =>
        opt.MapFrom(src => src.Invoices.Count()));
```

I got this Example from: http://codethug.com/2015/02/13/web-api-deep-dive-dto-transformations-and-automapper-part-5-of-6/

Arturo, you can use reverseMap on the CreateMap if it is not a complex mapping, to do a one-liner.